# Fill a string with words given from input

Tags: c++, string, iterator, char

**Input:**

`Today I eat bread. Today I eat cookies.`

**Output:**

```
eat: 2
        
I: 2
        
Today: 2

bread: 1

cookies: 1
```

I have to make a program that counts the number of times that a word occurs in the input. Then if the number of times is equal between some words, then I display them in alphabetic order. Until now I did this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int countt (string text);

int main () {
    string text;
    while (getline(cin,text))     //Receive the input here
    countt(text);                //Send the input to countt
    return 0;
}

int countt (string text) {
    int i,j;
    string aux;     //I make a string aux to put the word to compare here
        for (std::string::const_iterator i = text.begin(); *i != ' '; i++){
            for (std::string::const_iterator j = aux.begin(); j != text.end(); j++)
                *j=*i; //But here an error is given: 25:9: error: assignment of read-only location ‘j.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator*<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >()’
        }
        }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Using debugger each time and trying to find source of the bug yourself will halp you become a *self-sufficient programmer*. In contrast, asking for help each time you get an error will degrade your *problem solving abilities*.

Answer (score 1):

Referring specifically to the error comment you have in your code:

In your `for` loop you're using a `const_iterator` and then you're dereferencing that iterator and assigning to it, which you're not allowed to do because it's `const`.

Try again with `string::iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Read a line into a string, much like you do now. But then use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to tokenize the input. Use [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to store the words as keys and the count as data.

Comment: How do I use istringstream? I looker up but I don't understand very well how can I use it here..